# 配列の並び替えが上手くいかない。

Tags: java

Javaでメソッド「arraysSort」と「display」、「change」を定義して配列を昇順、降順に並び替えようとしています。

並び替え前はうまく出力できますが、並び替え後の昇順、降順データの出力方法がわかりません。
一応for文で回したりはしましたが、数がごちゃごちゃしてしまいうまく出力できませんでした。
お手数をおかけしますがご教授お願い致します。

ソースコード

```
package sample;

public class Kadai5_7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //配列データの宣言・初期化
        int[] arrays1 = { 96, 45, 31, 29, 84, 77 };
        //並び替え前の配列内を表示
        display(arrays1, false);
        //昇順で並び替えを実施
        arraysSort(arrays1, true);
        //並び替え後の配列内を表示
        display(arrays1, true);
        //降順で並び替えを実施
        arraysSort(arrays1, false);
        //並び替え後の配列内を表示
        display(arrays1, true);
    }

    public static void arraysSort(int[] array, boolean orderType) {
        if (orderType == true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                        change(array, i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                        change(array, i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void display(int[] array, boolean isSorted) {
        if (isSorted == true) {
            System.out.println("****並び替え後****");
        } else {
            System.out.println("****並び替え前****");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void change(int[] array, int i, int j) {
        int[] tmp = new int[array.length];
        tmp[i] = array[i];
        tmp[j] = array[j];
        array[i] = tmp[i];
        array[j] = tmp[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

並び替え前も並び替え後も「配列の要素を出力する」ことに変わりはないので、並び替え前と同じ処理が使えます。

```java
    public static void display(int[] array, boolean isSorted) {
        if (isSorted == true) {
            System.out.println("****並び替え後****");
        } else {
            System.out.println("****並び替え前****");
        }

        // 配列の出力方法は並び替え前後で同じ
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

---

質問内容からは逸れますが、おそらく出力結果は期待したものとは異なると思います(具体的には、「並び替え後」も並び替えられていない)。

これは、 `change` メソッドの入れ替え処理で実際には入れ替えできていないこと、`arraysSort` メソッドでで昇順/降順判定が逆になっているのが原因です(ので出力処理の問題ではないです)。

---

(追記: タイトルを見返して、並び替え自体についても言及されていることに気付きました)

`change` メソッドで行いたいのは、配列の `i` 番目の要素と `j` 番目の要素の入れ替えだと思いますが、現在のコードではそれができていません。
おそらく行いたいのは次のようなことだと思います:

```java
    public static void change(int[] array, int i, int j) {
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    }
```

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。